# How to find first specific item and then take 3 following?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to find position in a List based on where LINQ statement and get that item and next (x) amount. Example code:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
numbers = numbers.Where(elt => elt == 6).Take(3).ToList();
```

I am trying to get back a filtered list of 6,7,8. However this is not working. Am I approaching this wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost got it. You just need to change the `Where` to a `SkipWhile`:

```
numbers = numbers.SkipWhile(elt => elt != 6).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Why'll it pick 1 2 3?

Comment: Great answer Dennis :-:

Comment: I always forget about `SkipWhile`.  Good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Where()` overload that takes index of item as well and then use with `indexOf()`:

```
 List<int> numbers = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });

 var result = numbers.Where((x, i) => i >= numbers.IndexOf(6)).Take(3);
```

Comment: it will give the expected result.

Comment: It's a little bit cumbersome compared to [Dennis approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33145213/284240). It will also enumerate the list for every item in the list.

Comment: Better to `Skip(numbers.IndexOf(6)).Take(3)` but both of those will enumerate the list twice.  Not necessarily terrible for concrete collections, but a real no-no for enumerations.

Comment: @Corey: the `Where` will enumerate it n-times not only twice where n is the number of items in the sequence. So for every item it will calculate the first index of 6 again.

Comment: @Corey your suggested way is more better

Comment: @TimSchmelter You're right, I missed that.  Each item in the sequence will be passed to the condition delegate, which will enumerate the sequence to find the specified item.  My version with `Skip` only does it twice, but `Where` does it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach which comes into play when it's possible that the number is not unique and you want all occurences including the two next followers:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 6 });
numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Count)
    .Where(index => numbers[index] == 6)
    .SelectMany(index => numbers.Skip(index).Take(3))
    .ToList();  // 6,7,8,6,7,8,6
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach!